# Symfony Blog Filter Options

Tags: symfony

I've written a little blog in Symfony. Now I want to add a filter option.
For example, the user should be able to filter all posts according to certain categories.

Theoretically I have a working code for this. However, it is not possible to select multiple categories. How can I implement this. I know that I have to adapt the form, but that's not enough.

BlogFilterType:

```
 $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class, ['required' => false])
        ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Categories::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'required' => false,
        ])
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Filter anwenden']);
```

BlogPostsRepository.php:

```
public function findByFilters(array $filters, $page = 1, $postsPerPage = 6){
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->orderBy('a.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->leftJoin('a.categories', 'c');

    if (!empty($filters['title'])) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('a.title LIKE :title')
            ->setParameter('title', '%' . $filters['title'] . '%');
    }

    if (!empty($filters['category'])) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('c.name LIKE :category')
            ->setParameter('category', '%' . $filters['category'] . '%');
    }

    $paginator = new Paginator($queryBuilder);
    $paginator->getQuery()
        ->setFirstResult($postsPerPage * ($page -1))
        ->setMaxResults($postsPerPage);

    return $paginator;
 }
```

blogController.php

```
$form = $this->createForm(BlogFilterType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $filters = $form->getData();

        $posts = $bpr->findByFilters($filters);
```

Comment: First, you must set the `multiple` option of `EntityType` to `true`.